# How do we get the last day of the month from a given date

Tags: apex

Is there a function or method to give the last day of a month?
For example
if the date is 27 feb 2013, the last date should be 28 feb 2013 , it become 29 if its a leap year. if the date was 2 jan then it should return 31 Jan.

If there is no function then any ideas on how we can get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out salesforce [documentation on their Date class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm).

The method you are looking for is daysInMonth(...)

```
Integer numberOfDays = Date.daysInMonth(dateField.year(), dateField.month());
Date lastDayOfMonth = Date.newInstance(dateField.year(), dateField.month(), numberOfDays);
```

Keep in mind "dateField" above is a place holder for any Date variable or field you want to go off.

Comment: See the [Shailesh Deshpande's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9007/51878) for a short, clean one line answer.

Comment: this is fantastic! thank you!!!

Answer (score 53):

You can also use:

```
yourDate.addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1).
```

This will give you the last day of current month. What this basically does is it adds 1 month to current date and then use the toStartofMonth() to take you to the 1ST day of next month. Finally we are subtracting 1 day from the 1st day of next month which will give you the last day of current month.

Comment: I was initially concerned with how `yourDate.addMonths(1)` will handle 1/31, but it appears safe. It returns the exact date from the next month, and if next month is shorter, it returns the last day of next month. So, for 1/31, it will return 2/28 or 2/29.